# Polymorphism and overloading properties which are "static" for a given type in the class hierarchy

Tags: c#, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have to interact with different hardwares (but all from the same family) by sending commands. To store commands I was previously using an enum. However, now there are different hws and depending on the firmware version it is possible to have (i) new commands in addition to the base ones and/or (ii) different values for some of the base ones. Hardwares implement an interface (let's call it `IHw`) and a base abstract class (`HwBase`), which provides also base functionalities.

Hence I thought to convert the enum to a class with virtual properties in order to override or add functionalities. Something like:

```
public class CmdBase
{
    public virtual int SET_LED { get { return 0x10; } }
}
public class Cmd1 : CmdBase
{
    //override base command
    public override int SET_LED { get { return 0x20; } }
}
public class Cmd2 : CmdBase
{
    //add a functionality 
    public virtual int SET_LED_2 { get { return 0x30; } }
}
```

Do you think this is the right way? And if yes, which is the right way to use these commands so that each hw access its own commands and by having a some sort of Polymorphism? I thought maybe generics might help, but I'm not sure. Instead of posting the attempts I tried to use, I post a sort of pseudo-code (that makes easier to understand), which would work in case (but of course it is not possible) properties where static and static methods were overridable:

```
public abstract class HwBase : IHw
{
    public virtual void SetLED()
    {
        // base implementation should send 0x10
        SendCommand(CmdBase.SET_LED);
    }
}
public class Hw1 : HwBase
{
    public override void SetLED()
    {
        // should send 0x20
        SendCommand(Cmd1.SET_LED);
    }
}
public class Hw2 : HwBase
{
    public virtual void SetLED2()
    {
        // should send 0x30
        SendCommand(Cmd2.SET_LED_2);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

a more "real" example of what I have. This is a method in `HwBase` where I'm using the commands defined in `Cmd` enum.

```
protected virtual bool SetFilter()
{
if (!SendCommand(new byte[] { Cmd.SET_HP_COEF_A1, (byte)(a1Conv >> 8), (byte)(a1Conv & 0xff), 0 }) ||
    !SendCommand(new byte[] { Cmd.SET_HP_COEF_B0, (byte)(b0Conv >> 8), (byte)(b0Conv & 0xff), 0 }) ||
    !SendCommand(new byte[] { Cmd.SET_HP_COEF_B1, (byte)(b1Conv >> 8), (byte)(b1Conv & 0xff), 0 }) ||
    !SendCommand(new byte[] { Cmd.SET_HP_COEF_D1, (byte)(d1Conv >> 8), (byte)(d1Conv & 0xff), 0 }) ||
    !SendCommand(new byte[] { Cmd.SET_HP_COEF_D2, (byte)(d2Conv >> 8), (byte)(d2Conv & 0xff), 0 }) ||
    !SendCommand(new byte[] { Cmd.SET_FILTER_MODE, 0, 0, 0}) )
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Then in the derived Hw1, according to the firmware version, I might need a totally different procedure with other commands. I would like to have these commands in addition to the `Cmd` ones,but visible only to `Hw1`. Now they are inside another enum, `CmdLegacy`, that has most of the commands defined in `Cmd` (copied and pasted) plus some identical commands defined in `Cmd` **but** with a different value and some new commands (in this way code maintenance is not simple if you consider that there are hundreds of commands and several hws). I instead would like to reuse commands defined in `Cmd` without copying and pasting them in `CmdLegacy`, but just changing those that are different and adding the new ones.

```
protected override bool SetFilter()
{
    if (isLegacyFirmware)
    {
        byte msg1;
        switch (filterValue)
        {
            default:
            case 0: msg1 = CmdLegacy.FILTER_CONST_758; break;
            case 1: msg1 = CmdLegacy.FILTER_CONST_1517; break;
            case 2: msg1 = CmdLegacy.FILTER_CONST_3034; break;
            case 3: msg1 = CmdLegacy.FILTER_CONST_6068; break;
            case 4: msg1 = CmdLegacy.FILTER_CONST_12136; break;
            case 5: msg1 = CmdLegacy.FILTER_CONST_24272; break;
        }

        byte msg2 = dataType == 0 ? CmdLegacy.UNFILTERED : CmdLegacy.FILTERED;

        return SendCommand(new byte[] { CmdLegacy.SET_FILTER_MODE, msg1, msg2, 0 });
    }
    return base.SetFilter();
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the word _static_ in this context, but you're on the right track. Write your implementation for `SendCommand` in the abstract class, then call `base.SendCommand(x)` with the appropriate value for each descendant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use generics, even if I'm still not sure whether it is the right/more elegant approach. Giving the `CmdBase`, `Cmd1` and `Cmd2` as in the question, the hardware classes became:

```
public abstract class HwBase<T> where T : CmdBase, new()
{
    protected static readonly T Commands = new T();
    public virtual void SetLED()
    {
        SendCommand(Commands.SET_LED); // 0x10
    }
}

public class Hw1 : HwBase<Cmd1>
{
    public override void SetLED()
    {
        SendCommand(Commands.SET_LED); // 0x20
    }
}
public class Hw2 : HwBase<Cmd2>
{
    public override void SetLED2()
    {
        SendCommand(Commands.SET_LED_2); // 0x30
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An object model such as the one you describe would look like this:

```
public abstract class HwBase : IHw
{

    protected void SendCommand(int x)
    {
        // Send the value of 'x' to the appropriate device
    }

    public virtual void SetLED();

}

public class Hw1 : HwBase
{
    public override void SetLED()
    {
        // should send 0x20
        base.SendCommand(0x20);
    }
}

public class Hw2 : HwBase
{
    public virtual void SetLED()
    {
        // should send 0x30
        base.SendCommand(0x30);
    }
}
```

The only question mark is how you're going to determine which one is the target device.

Comment: thanks for the example, however I would like the commands to be defined somewhere (e.g. in a class) so that they are not spread in the code but only in one location. Moreover I would like to reuse as much as possible of those commands (i.e. I do not want to have 200 commands defined for a given hw and 203 for another hw that differs in reality for only 3 commands).

Comment: What you're describing is a command design pattern, and doesn't require inheritance. For example, you could create a class `SetLed` with a procedure `Execute()` that takes a parameter that indicates the target device. Inside this procedure, you would then call `SendCommand` with the appropriate parameters.

If this is too vague, show us your code as it is at the moment.

Comment: The thing is that you have to define all 200 commands in one way or another, but it doesn't necessarily mean that you have to copy/paste the same block of code 200 times.

Comment: I've posted a more detailed example of what I have